# Arangoimp crashes randomly on data import to ArangoDB

Tags: c++, arangodb

I'm working with ArangoDB 3.0. The process involves ingesting JSON data into ArangoDB using arangoimp.

However i keep getting this error at random on executing arangoimp and the process exits.

```
2017-03-02T10:49:00Z [29652] ERROR error message:    Expecting type Array (exception location: /usr/src/packages/BUILD/arangod/HttpServer/HttpHandler.cpp:157). Please report this error to arangodb.com
```

On checking the file i found that the arrays are in proper format. On executing arangoimp the second time, the error occurs at a different part of the file.

Please can you help in fixing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend posting this issue on the [issues page at GitHub for ArangoDB](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues).

It will get tracked there and you can see the progress of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

On checking further, i found a bug in ArangoDB in github https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/2133 . This issue got resolved, once i removed all the persistent indexes, Ingested the data and then turned on the Persistent Indices.